# System should not refresh after clicking on already selected radio button

Tags: radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons , i selected one to them , there is an ajax call when i select that , what i want that there should not be any ajax call when i click on the already selected radio button . How to implement this.

```
    <label for="cooperativeAuthorisedRepresentativeType">#{msg['com.crimsonlogic.egov.rol.rnra.landsubdivision.applicantdetails.cooperative.cooperativeAuthorisedRepresentativeType']}</label>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="applicantDetails_cooperative_cooperativeAuthorisedRepresentativeType" required="true"
            value="#{landSubdivisionController.cooperativeDetails.repCode}" requiredMessage="#{cmn['rol.common.message.error.RADIO_REQUIRED']}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['REPRWAND']}" itemValue="REPRWAND" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['REPFOR']}" itemValue="REPFOR" />
            <f:validateRequired />
            <a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{landSubdivisionController.changeRepresentativeTypeForCooperative()}" render="cooperativeCitizenNationalId,cooperativeCitizenNationalIdForFranchisee,cooperativeCitizenSurname,cooperativeCitizenOtherNames,cooperativeCitizenDistrict,cooperativeCitizenSector,cooperativeCitizenCell,cooperativeCitizenVillage,cooperativeForeignerPassportNo,cooperativeForeignerSurname,cooperativeForeignerOtherNames,cooperativeForeignerCountry,cooperativeForeignerCity"  />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h:message for="applicantDetails_cooperative_cooperativeAuthorisedRepresentativeType" styleClass="help-block"></h:message>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change` event instead of `click` event of javascript.

You can try writing like this:
`<a4j:ajax event="change"`